# Auto Nofollow attribute in custom field links. How?

Tags: nofollow

I have a wordpress network. All the contents in my network are user generated. All posts links are now dofollow. I want to change it to nofollow.  My site uses plugin for custom fields. I removed the default description area. So i cannot use the_content function. I use custom fields for all.

I tried many auto nofollow plugins. But its not working in my custom fields.
Can anyone help me?

Is there any function code available?

I just want

```
<a href="http://domain.com">My Link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://domain.com" rel="nofollow">My Link</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the output of your custom fields look like?

Comment: Hey bro, I found a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/1476839). I think it will work.Let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Available [here](https://gist.github.com/1476839) which is written by [chrisguitarguy](http://www.christopherguitar.net/)